# Python SOAP Reaquest And Response TO/FROM a WEB SERVICE

Tags: python, soap-client

Hi i do googling and i faced with Various Problem such as :

> ```
> raise TypeNotFound(self.ref)
> ```
>
> suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(schema, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )'

I need to get response From:

> http://www.tsetmc.com/WebService/TsePublicV2.asmx
>    http://www.tsetmc.com/WebService/TsePublicV2.asmx?WSDL

See This Help:
[HELP](http://www.tsetmc.com/WebService/TsePublicV2.asmx?op=Company)
How Can Get Response From This Service in Python 3:

> 1: username:mgamini
>   2. password:123456
>   3. Flow:0

My Basic Code that i use with error is:

```
from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor, Import
from suds.client import Client


url = 'http://www.tsetmc.com/WebService/TsePublicV2.asmx?WSDL'
imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp.filter.add('http://some/namespace/A')
doctor = ImportDoctor(imp)
client = Client(url, doctor=doctor)
```

and i get"

> ```
> raise TypeNotFound(self.ref)
> ```
>
> suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(schema, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )'

PLZ HELP ME on THIS
Sincerely Yours!!!

Comment: tnx ahmad! but any response to Question?

Answer (score 0):

YOU Should ASK YOUR Question COMMONLY,
i'm really intrest about Your main QOuestion,
Python SOAP Reaquest And Response TO/FROM a WEB SERVICE
with XML input and output!